# client-server protocol for sensor data and command transmission using python

Tags: python, flask, client-server, mqtt, network-protocols

Unfortunately I have very little experience in this kind of topics so I have been stalled for a while (while searching around and reading for possible solutions).

My issue is quite simple, I have a system that works like this:

- A client device (for now a raspberry pi; consider multiple devices in future), both reads sensor data and controls some actuators.
- A server (my pc for now) would like to elaborate this data and send commands to the remote actuators (obviously depending on the elaboration it does).

***Therefore, basically, what I need is*** for 'n' clients to connect to a specific server address and provide sensor data every 'x' minutes. Then, I would like the server to send specific commands to specific clients' actuators when it feels the need (the clients needs to listen for commands or pull periodically the commands from the server).

I am a bit confused on the variety of protocols and modules available and on the best way to go from here. In particular I am looking for something quite lightweight, that could scale well (if lots of clients will connect) and that doesn't require low-level implementations (I am trying to avoid to handling sockets myself and define my own protocol).

***Extra info:***
Just to give you some context, I have mainly considered:

- MQTT, but it seems to me that I would have to put a broker on what I call "server" and then use the server as a client that connects to a localhost broker for subscriptions...this seems wrong. I mean, the broker now is the problem, how do I solve that?
- webframework like Flask with some sort of REST get/post requests to send data to the server...seems a bit heavy solution and the server doesn't have a way to push commands to the client...the client would have to check periodically.

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: @hardillb Read the title and if you have some doubts the bold part tells you what I need to achieve ;)

Comment: What you've asked is for a recommendation, which will be primarily opinion based, both of which are off topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: @hardillb I asked for a lightweigth protocol that can fit a specific communication scenario, e.g., for a solution to this communication problem. Then, if we state that a solution is de facto a recommendation to use that solution and therefore an opinion...well, stack overflow becomes pointless...

Comment: @Bertone "*Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow [...]*". See also the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @AndrasDeak asking for a possible  communication protocol that solves a specific communication pattern seems to me very different from asking for books, libraries or tools. Also, your link confirms my impression...nevertheless, if I am wrong, I am sure this question will be closed soon, so it's  pointless to continue this discussion further (my last reply on this matter).

Comment: I perfectly agree (re: pointlessness), I wasn't trying to start an argument. I'm only leaving a comment (my last one too) to note that [software recs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might be more suitable for this question. I'm not familiar with that site, but this would be my guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## MQTT

MQTT is a lightweight subscriber/publisher protocol for IOT (and not only), that is heavily developed in this area.

If your client devices are Raspberry Pi's (or any other devices that run Linux OS) then MQTT is probably the way to go. Your distribution most likely provides MQTT broker (called `mosquitto`) that will run out of the box after installation. You can easily test it installing `mosquitto-clients`, it will provide you `mosquitto_sub` and `mosquitto_pub` command line api.

This will allow you easy two-way communication. MQTT provides various client libraries for most languages (including Python, C, C++, Perl, Java, it supports even web sockets) on various platforms (including bare-metal), so it integrates with any systems nicely.

If your future client device is simple uC then you should look whether there is support for MQTT (most likely, there is, with a whole bunch of tutorials).

You can easily manage MQTT brokers, put them into cloud using bridges if you want, or manage separately via IP hostnames. It's extremely easy to learn and very fun to use.